# Generating Content, PHP Style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dynamic

I'm currently developing a PHP website that acts similarly to a reminders program.

On most of my other websites, I use jQuery to generate the layout by appending div objects, because they don't have any connection with a database.

Now that I am using more server based operations, my plan is to build template php files first, then use functions to generate dynamic content (such as a div for each task). What is the CORRECT and widely implemented method to generate dynamic elements using php such as..

1. Multiple sections (Divs)
2. Buttons
3. Pop ups
4. Forms

I guess my final question is, should PHP be generating the content, or should the content be passed via JSON and handled by javascript. Which is more appropriate.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just write pure html into a string and use the echo function.

Comment: Is that the most common way to append html content? To me it seems rather unorganized. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well the 'common' way is to use php for parsing of information and javascript for the interactivity and layouts of the website, not php for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically i would suggest to just put the HTML into a string and output this with PHP.

For more structure i separate some sections into different files, these files are then just included at each dynamic page.

For example:

On top of the file i create the dynamic information with php, 
then there are some includes of other dynamic/static information like:
- page header, which can be used for all pages, and also could be party dynamic. eg for the page title.

- navigation menu
- then i create the actual page content
- include footer

Sample:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$title = 'This is my page title';

// do something
// create $content

include_once('includes/header.php');
include_once('includes/menu.php');

$output .= <<<HEREDOC
        <div class="content">
            {CONTENT}
        </div>\n
HEREDOC;

include_once('includes/footer.php');

$output = @preg_replace('/{CONTENT}/',$content,$output);


echo $output;

?>
```

Of course there are many ways to improve or extend this. But i hope this is a good sample.